# How to do this transpose?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this situation and cannot find a way with Pandas to do get the result I want.

I have this df with only one column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpoyU.png)

And I want to transpose to get like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRoea.png)

I alreary tried transpose but not getting the result i want.

And is there an easy way to put each value in a specif column?
For example: Y-1 in a column named Y-1, Y-3 in a column named Y-3. And if there is no Y-2 value, leave it blank in the column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcO0O.png)

Comment: Please write the dataframe as a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) and not an image in your question

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with dropping down to numpy to simply reshape. However, if there is a variable number of entries for each row, you can use a pivot with custom indices:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"MSG": ["MSG XXX", "Y-1", "Y-2", "Y-3", "Y-5", "Y-7", "Y-19", "MSG XYZ", "Y-1", "Y-3", "Y-11", "Y-12", "Y-17", "Y-19"]})

groups = df["MSG"].str.startswith("MSG").cumsum()
out = (
    df
    .assign(index=groups, columns=df.groupby(groups).cumcount())
    .pivot(index="index", columns="columns", values="MSG")
)
```

out:

```
columns        0    1    2     3     4     5     6
index
1        MSG XXX  Y-1  Y-2   Y-3   Y-5   Y-7  Y-19
2        MSG XYZ  Y-1  Y-3  Y-11  Y-12  Y-17  Y-19
```

Comment: Thanks!!
And is there an easy way to put each value in a specif column? For example: Y-1 in a column named Y-1, Y-3 in a column named Y-3. And if there is no Y-2 value, leave it blank in the column